# Fetching external api using spring boot giving null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

structure of api data I'm fetchingenter code here

```json
{
    "Global": {
        "NewConfirmed": 112797,
        "TotalConfirmed": 5399508,
        "NewDeaths": 6154,
        "TotalDeaths": 362859,
        "NewRecovered": 53574,
        "TotalRecovered": 1374979
    },
    "Countries": [
        {
            "Country": "Afghanistan",
            "CountryCode": "AF",
            "Slug": "afghanistan",
            "NewConfirmed": 255,
            "TotalConfirmed": 4033,
            "NewDeaths": 6,
            "TotalDeaths": 115,
            "NewRecovered": 30,
            "TotalRecovered": 502,
            "Date": "2020-05-10T16:31:50Z"
        },
        {
            "Country": "Albania",
            "CountryCode": "AL",
            "Slug": "albania",
            "NewConfirmed": 6,
            "TotalConfirmed": 856,
            "NewDeaths": 0,
            "TotalDeaths": 31,
            "NewRecovered": 7,
            "TotalRecovered": 627,
            "Date": "2020-05-10T16:31:50Z"
        },
        {
            "Country": "Algeria",
            "CountryCode": "DZ",
            "Slug": "algeria",
            "NewConfirmed": 189,
            "TotalConfirmed": 5558,
            "NewDeaths": 6,
            "TotalDeaths": 494,
            "NewRecovered": 79,
            "TotalRecovered": 2546,
            "Date": "2020-05-10T16:31:50Z"
        },
```

method fetching data

```java
    public Post getEmployees(){
        RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        Post list =   rest.getForObject("https://api.covid19api.com/summary", Post.class);
        return list;
    }
```

POJO Classes: All pojo classes have getter and setters and constructor

Post

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Post {

    private Global global;

    private Country[] countries;




}
```

Global

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Global {

    private Long newconfirmed;
    private Long totalconfirmed;
    private Long newdeaths;
    private Long totaldeaths;
    private Long newrecovered;
    private Long totalrecovered;
```

Country

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Country {

    private String country;
    private String countryCode;
    private String slug;
    private Long newconfirmed;
    private Long totalconfirmed;
    private Long newdeaths;
    private Long totaldeaths;
    private Long newrecovered;
    private Long totalrecovered;
    private String date;
```

Controller

```java
    @GetMapping(produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public Post getAliens() {
        return repo.getEmployees();
    }
```

output i'm getting

```json
{
    "global": null,
    "countries": null
}
```

Comment: `"Global"` != `"global"`, so of course the input JSON doesn't map to any fields in your `Post` class. Add `@JsonProperty("Global")` to the field. Same for **all** the other fields too.

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Your question is okay, but you should add some more details about your project, to help the community help you.

Comment: @Andreas thanks its working fine now. Thanks again

Comment: @rainer actually this was my first question. But thanks for your suggestion. I will keep this in mind next time.